# How to get the username of the user who lastly modified a particular file in a directory in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, audit, inotify

I want to get the **username** who modified a file in **watched directory** in *LINUX* operating system (UBUNTU).

I am getting notification of modified file in watched directory through `inotify`, but I **didn't get username** who modified.

I used `auditctl` for adding same **watch directory path** which is added in the `inotify` and getting information using `ausearch`

But I am getting whole information about file which is modified in **watched directory** which is totally not my use.

I want username specifically who recently modified that file which is in the **watch directory**.

I refer https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-testsuite this for installing and using `auditctl`.

My main task is to get username who last modified a particular file, how can I do this?

Comment: There is a race condition, but you could `lsof thefile` right after you receive from `inotify` that the file is opened/modified. But if the file is opened by multiple users, you wouldn't know who from them modified it.

Comment: Per the comments, this is a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do what you ask in C. Everything you can know about a file can be retrieved through the [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) syscall. This does not include any information about which user or group lastly modified the file, since it is something that is simply not tracked by the system, not even with SELinux enabled.

Comment: Auditing - if configured properly - will definitely record the opening and modification of the file, including the user. It won't do that in real-time, however, and only privileged users would have access to the audit data.

Comment: yes , you are right . But it gives extra non-required info using "ausearch" command . If you modified a file then it gives info of file and also gives .swp , .swx of that  file. So , i can't get specific section which having that specific file info

Comment: @AndrewHenle OP tagged this question as C and is talking about specific syscalls. There is no way to do what OP asks for with a simple C program, that's what I meant.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli That's a fair assessment of the question.  I wonder exactly what problems the OP is having extracting the username from audit data, though.

Comment: @AndrewHenle      inotify – how to find out which user has modified file

Comment: @MarcoBonelli inotify – how to find out which user has modified file

Comment: @AnupAgrawal You can't.